# Pass an object to my timer

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters, sender

If I check with the debugger inside the `sender` parameter, I can see my object with all its properties, but how can I access those properties? I have tried `MyClass mc = MyClass as sender` but it's null.

Here's my timer's tick event:

```
private void timerP_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

And here is the event that starts my timer:

```
void class_startTimerEvent(MyClass class)
{
    timerP.Tag = class;

    if (InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { timerP.Start(); });
    else
        timerP.Start();
}
```

Comment: Does timerP is of type `Timer` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a `EventHandler` that uses the standard implementation the `sender` parameter is always the object that raises the event, in your case it's the `timerP` object.

So you can get your `MyClass` object using

```
var timer = (Timer) sender;
var myClass = (MyClass) timer.Tag;
```